# UNIX based calendar solution that works with Mac, iPhone, and Linux

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical, caldav, evolution

I wonder what open source group calendaring solution people are using that works with Apple devices *and* Linux.

ATM we use Apple's CalendarServer but this one seems to have trouble with the existing Linux clients (Evolution, Thunderbird/Lightning). Also, invites do not really work, and sometimes appointments appear on calendars of persons that were never invited.

I just can't believe that everybody is using Exchange nowadays. There has to be someone who has a working CalDAV solution with around one hundred users.

What do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Davical, very satisfied with it. Easy to use and with LDAP support.

Comment: How many users does this installation serve? Do invitations work flawlessly? Even with Evolution and the iPhone? Do recurring events work?

Comment: Approx 40 users. Not sure about invitations. iPhone OK, Thunderbird OK, Evolution not tested. Recurring events are working.